# Loadrunner web_custom_request analog in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am pretty new to load testing and whole web thing.
Is there any way to implement things that this Vugen Loadrunner code do

```
     web_custom_request("action", 
      "{URL}", 
      "Method=POST", 
      "Resource=0", 
      "RecContentType=text/html", 
      "Referer={refURL}", 
      "Snapshot=t57.inf", 
      "Mode=HTTP", 
      "Body={PARAMETER}",
      LAST);
```

In jmeter? The {PARAMETER} is just a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's equivalent would be [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

[JMeter's Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) have a little bit different syntax so the equivalent configuration would be something like:

[image]

If you want to have full control there is also [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Also be aware that you can record your LoadRunner script using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and in LoadRunner's Runtime Settings set JMeter as the proxy:

[image]

When you run your LoadRunner test JMeter will capture the requests and save them under [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

[image]

More information: [How to Convert LoadRunner Tests to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

To send any kind of HTTP Request you can use [HTTP Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

To start with use this practical example : [build-web-test-plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) and then move to advanced [build-adv-web-test-plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

[Parameterization in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) and 
[Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

Being a performance tester/engineer/architect brings with it a core ability to recognize patterns associated with success and failure

> I am pretty new to load testing and whole web thing.

This is a massive antipattern for success in this field.  You need your foundation skills vetted and shored up.  You really do need training and a mentor for a period of time.

If your management is asking you to perform in this role, then they should also ensure your path to success.  If they are unwilling to fund your training and mentoring period, then I would recommend seeking new management who are more interested in your success and the success of the project.